# how to count the highlighted words in Algolia search

Tags: search, highlight, algolia

**Hello guys**
how could I count number of highlighted words in *Algolia* search including the duplicate word in the same hit

Answer (score 0):

Algolia only tracks the number of records that match, not the number of highlighted words. You'd have to traverse the `hits` object yourself to calculate that information based on the <em> tags in each `_highlightResult`.

What are you using it for?